# Kivy with Menubar

Tags: python, kivy

I want to create a Kivy-App with a Menubar which is always the same.

My Code:

**demo.py**:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Display(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Screen_One(Screen):
    pass

class Screen_Two(Screen):
    pass

class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Display()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

**demo.kv**:

```
<Display>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: '48dp'
            Button:
                text: 'One'
                on_release: sm.current = 'Screen_One'
            Button:
                text: 'Two'
                on_release: sm.current = 'Screen_Two'

        ScreenManager:
            id: sm
            Screen_One:
            Screen_Two:

<Screen_One>:
    Button:
        text: 'One'

<Screen_Two>:
    Button:
        text: 'Two'
```

But it doesn't work, if i click on "One" i received:

> kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "Screen_One".

I reduced my code to the leading part. I also tried to put the menu-kivy-code in a seperate file and import but then i also can't access the ScreenManager and can't switch the Screens.

Answer (score 6):

[`ScreenManager.current`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.current) atribute is the **name** of the screen currently shown. You have not set the name attribute in your classes (screens). Your `demo.kv` file should be:

```
<Display>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: '48dp'
            Button:
                text: 'One'
                on_release: sm.current = 'screen_one'  #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            Button:
                text: 'Two'
                on_release: sm.current = 'screen_two'  #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

        ScreenManager:
            id: sm
            Screen_One:
            Screen_Two:

<Screen_One>:
    name: 'screen_one'      #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Button:
        text: 'One'

<Screen_Two>:
    name: 'screen_two'      #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Button:
        text: 'Two'
```

[image]