# kivy menu bar with screen manager and new menu on separate screens

Tags: kivy

This answer shows how to make a menu that switches between screens.  [Kivy with Menubar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770222/kivy-with-menubar)

But now that I am on screen two, I need to put two buttons on that screen

An Ok and a Cancel button.

OK takes you to a screen that says the information was processed,

Cancel takes me back to screen one per the example.

I have tried putting in a second screenmanager but it doesn't like that.  How is this handled?

```
<Display>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: '48dp'
            Button:
                text: 'One'
                on_release: 
                    sm.current = 'screen_one'  #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                    sm.transition.direction = "left"
            Button:
                text: 'Two'
                on_release: 
                    sm.current = 'screen_two'  #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                    sm.transition.direction = "right"
            Button:
                text: 'Three'
                on_release: 
                    sm.current = 'screen_three'  #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                    sm.transition.direction = "right"

        ScreenManager:
            id: sm
            Screen_One:
            Screen_Two:
            Screen_Three:

<Screen_One>:
    name: 'screen_one'      #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Button:
        text: 'One'
    


<Screen_Two>:
    name: 'screen_two'      #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: '48dp'

        Button:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_release: 
                sm1.current = 'screen_one'  #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                sm1.transition.direction = "left"

        Button:
            text: 'Ok'
            on_release: 
                sm1.current = 'screen_three'  #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                sm1.transition.direction = "right"

    ScreenManager:
        id: sm1
        Screen_One:
        Screen_Two:
        Screen_Three:
            
    

<Screen_Three>:
    name: 'screen_three'      #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Button:
        text: 'Three'
```

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of `Screen` has a `manager` property, which is a reference to the `ScreenManager` that is managing it. So, in your `kv`, you can replace `sm1` with `root.manager` like this:

```
            root.manager.current = 'screen_three'  #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```